# strictly dominated strategy

Tags: game-theory, economics, nash-equilibrium

**PROBLEM**

Proof that if a pure strategy is strictly dominated, then any mixed strategy that assigns positive probability will also be strictly dominated by some other mixed strategy.

i.e

If $s_{i}\in S_{i}$ is strictly dominated
$\forall \widetilde{\sigma_{i}}\in \sum_{i}$ , $\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}(s_{i})>0$, 
$\exists{\sigma_{i}}\in \sum_{i}$ s.t

$\forall{s_{-i}}\in S_{-i}$: 
 $\prod_{i}(\sigma_{i},s_{-i})>\prod_{i}(\widetilde{\sigma_{i}},s_{-i})$

**Solution**

Suppose...

$\forall{\sigma_{i}}\in \sum_{i} \ , \ \exists {s_{-i}}\in S_{-i}$: 
 $\prod_{i}(\sigma_{i},s_{-i})\leq \prod_{i}(\widetilde{\sigma_{i}},s_{-i})$

in particular we choose to be strictly dominated by $\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}$

$\prod_{i}(\sigma_{i},s_{-i})\leq \prod_{i}(\widetilde{\sigma_{i}},s_{-i})$

if $A=\prod_{i}(\sigma_{i},s_{-i})=\sum_{s_{i}\in S_{i}}\sigma_{i}\prod_{i}(s_{i},s_{-i})$...................$(\alpha)$

But $s_{i}\in S_{i}$ is strictly dominated it is : $\exists \sigma_{i}\in \sum_{i} , \forall s_{-i}\in S_{-i}$ s.t

$\prod_{i}(s_{i},s_{-i})<\prod_{i}(\sigma_{i},s_{-i})$ using $(\alpha)$

$\prod_{i}(s_{i},s_{-i})<\sum_{s_{i}\in S_{i}}\sigma_{i}\prod_{i}(s_{i},s_{-i})$ multiplication $\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}$

$\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}\prod_{i}(s_{i},s_{-i})<\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}A$

$\sum_{s_{i}\in S_{i}}\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}\prod_{i}(s_{i},s_{-i})<\sum_{s_{i}\in S_{i}}\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}A$

But $\sum_{s_{i}\in S_{i}}\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}\prod_{i}(s_{i},s_{-i})=\prod_{i}(\widetilde{\sigma_{i}},s_{-i})$

Finally $A\leq \prod_{i}(\widetilde{\sigma_{i}},s_{-i})<\sum_{s_{i}\in S_{i}}\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}A$

$A<A\sum_{s_{i}\in S_{i}}\widetilde{\sigma_{i}}$

$A<A$ (Absurd)

**This is correct?**

The teacher indicated that it is a direct consequence of the definition.
But I do not see it as direct, in fact it is proposed as an exercise.
I would like to know if someone has experience with this topic, so that you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the notation you're using, but the basic idea is pretty simple. Suppose there is some strategy that is dominated. Call it `strategy1`. Since it's dominated, there is some strategy that dominates it. Call it `strategy2`. Suppose there is some mixed strategy `ms1` that assigns `strategy1` non-zero probability p, and probability 1-p to some other mix of strategies. Then define `ms2` as gibing probability 1-p to that same mix of other strategies, and assigning probability p to `strategy2` instead of `strategy1`. Then `ms2` dominates `ms1`.

Comment: Is this justification enough?
I expected to use some mathematical theory of Games. 
thanks for your help.

Comment: @user553004 this justification is usually enough but you should write it all out in terms of expected utility (with all the quantifiers, using the definitions you're given). The idea is the same but you'll be convinced then.